# How to combine flask_ldap3_login and flask_httpauth in a Flask app and test the authentication against ldap.forumsys.com

Tags: authentication, flask, active-directory, ldap, basic-authentication

I have been struggling to combine flask_ldap3_login and flask_httpauth into a simple Flask app and test the result against the only free LDAP server that's available: ldap.forumsys.com

There a lot of information out there but none showed how to set all the config parameters correctly to get it to work just right. After a lot of trial and error, I got it to work.

If you have a better/simpler solution, please share!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code (I'll also be sharing in https://gist.github.com/jeromegit/f987b081afa3cbc09ed47a3089b32079):
(Also check out the information re: the free LDAP server: https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ )

```
from flask import Flask
import logging
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager, AuthenticationResponseStatus
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

# Extra logging to help troubleshoot
logging.getLogger('flask_ldap3_login').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('flask_ldap3_login')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(realm="Private!")

# Setup LDAP Configuration Variables. Change these to your own settings.
# All configuration directives can be found in the documentation.
# See https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/
config = dict()

# Hostname of your LDAP Server
config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'ldap.forumsys.com'

# The Username to bind to LDAP with
config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com'

# The Password to bind to LDAP with
config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

# Base DN of your directory
config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'dc=example,dc=com'

# Users DN to be prepended to the Base DN
#config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = 'ou=scientists'

# Groups DN to be prepended to the Base DN
config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = ''

# The RDN attribute for your user schema on LDAP
config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'uid'

# The Attribute you want users to authenticate to LDAP with.
config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'uid'

config['LDAP_GROUP_OBJECT_FILTER'] = '(objectclass=*)'

# Setup a LDAP3 Login Manager.
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager()

# Init the manager with the config
ldap_manager.init_config(config)


@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    # Check if the credentials are correct
    response = ldap_manager.authenticate(username, password)
    if response.status == AuthenticationResponseStatus.success:
        return username
    else:
       print(response.status)

@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def index():
    return "Hello, {}!".format(auth.current_user())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5003)
```